# Group By on Multiple Columns with Datetimes

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a pair of tables on 2 separate SQL Servers that have data I need and identical columns. I have used a Union All to get them into a single table to query from but when i try to use a group by to get their BatchID, Start Time, and End Time i get an error.

My Query:

```
 Select BatchID, cast(StartTime as datetime2(0)) as StartTime,
        cast(EndTime as datetime2(0)) as EndTime 
 from derp 
 group by BatchID, Cast(StartTime as Date), Cast(EndTime as Date)
```

My Error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>      Column 'derp.StartTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

I have the start time and end time in the group by clause but it is saying i do not. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `CAST` to `DATE` in the `SELECT` clause as well:

```
 Select BatchID, Cast(StartTime as Date), Cast(EndTime as Date)
 from derp 
 group by BatchID, Cast(StartTime as Date), Cast(EndTime as Date)
```

Comment: Though I needed them in DateTime2(0) the solution worked by using that cast in the group by clause, thanks loads.